# Trying to do a counter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm creating a number guessing game in Python. I need to do a counter for three trials. I did the code below and it didn't work.

```
secretNum = input('Guess number 1 to 5: ')  # the guessed number
random_number = random.randrange(1, 6) # the secret number
ssent = random.choice(sent)

def numba():
    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        if count < 3:
            if int(secretNum) == random_number:
                print(f'''Yaay you guessed right 
                The secret number is {random_number}''')
            elif int(secretNum) < random_number:
                print(f'''HINT
                Guessed number is less than secret number {random_number}''')
            elif int(secretNum) > random_number:
                print(f'''HINT
                Guessed number is more than secret number {random_number}''')
            else:
                print('so close yet so far!!')
                count +=1
            break
    return
numba()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 'count' variable will increase only 'else', you should put it outside 'else'.
I think you will give the user 3 chances of guesses, then you will need to get the inputs from the user 3 times. So you need

```py
secretNum = input('Guess number 1 to 5: ')
```

in the while loop.

The code you want should be something like this.

```py
def numba():
    count = 0
    random_number = random.randrange(1, 6)
    while count < 3:
        userGuess = input('Guess number 1 to 5: ')
        # if count < 3: # you don't need this, you already have while loop.
        if int(userGuess) == random_number:
            print(f'''Yaay you guessed right 
            The secret number is {random_number}''')
            # User guessed it right! Stop the while loop.
            break
        elif int(userGuess) < random_number:
            print(f'''HINT
            Guessed number is less than secret number {random_number}''')
        elif int(userGuess) > random_number:
            print(f'''HINT
            Guessed number is more than secret number {random_number}''')
        else:
            print('so close yet so far!!')
        count +=1
```

Comment: the counter is still not woking

Comment: @anthonymensah Hi, What do you mean by "counter"? Can you clarify the game rules a bit more? Why it is still not working and how should it work?

Comment: The game is a guess game with allows a person to guess a number. The person guessing has 3 chances to guess correctly. The counter is the variable which will ensure that the game stops after the person guesses three wrong numbers

Comment: @anthonymensah Hi, the code seems to do what you ask. It stopped after 3 incorrect tries. Can you clarify a bit more how the code doesn't work for you?